# Unable to access to Swift 4.2 class included in a framework into Objective C Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I've got a framework built in both Objective C and Swift. I've upgraded it from Swift 3 to Swift 4.2, and now, after exporting it through Aggregate target and importing the generated framework inside my Objective C demo app, it doesn't show me any Swift class.

I've already checked if `-swift.h` is correctly builded, and I can see inside it all Swift classes. However, even if I import the `umbrella` header inside my demo app, I can't see them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Swift generates code that is only available to other Swift code, but if you need to interact with the Objective-C runtime – all of UIKit, for example – you need to tell Swift what to do.

That’s where the @objc attribute comes in: when you apply it to a class or method it instructs Swift to make those things available to Objective-C as well as Swift code. So, any time you want to call a method from a UIBarButtonItem or a Timer, you’ll need to mark that method using @objc so it’s exposed – both of those, and many others, are Objective-C code.

```
class MyController: UIViewController {
    @objc func authenticateUser() {

    }
```

To make this class accessible from Objective-C, we need to add the @objc keyword just before the class declaration. This tells the compiler to do some magic behind the scenes (namely, create an invisible header file)

```
@objc class SwiftViewController: UIViewController {
// ... 
}
```

Reference - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objc-attribute